# jQuery mobile AJAX calls stripping out custom scripts

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-tabs

First of all, I am new JQM and a pretty weak jQuery coder but am looking for a little help...

I have a jQuery Mobile site going quite nicely and have just implemented jQuery tabs into it. I call to the script via  within the  tags and the script goes as follows:

```
$('ul.tabs').each(function(){
    // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
    // which tab is active and it's associated content
    var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

    // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
    // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
    $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
    $active.addClass('active');
    $content = $($active.attr('href'));

    // Hide the remaining content
    $links.not($active).each(function () {
        $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
    });

    // Bind the click event handler
    $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
        // Make the old tab inactive.
        $active.removeClass('active');
        $content.hide();

        // Update the variables with the new link and content
        $active = $(this);
        $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

        // Make the tab active.
        $active.addClass('active');
        $content.show();

        // Prevent the anchor's default click action
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

This all works fine in my site until I utilise a pagination script which is attached to CMS component for Flickr gallery's which alters the address bar in the browser.

I see that JQM has some slightly different ways of handling custom JS files but I was hoping someone out there might be able to offer a little more support for newb like me.

Comment: "I call to the script via within the tags"...Are you saying the script is embedded in the page? If so, where in the page?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified... I call a scripts.js file within the header which at this point only contains the scripts for the tabs (code above). When the pagination of the flickr gallery is clicked it seems to refresh the page with a slightly changed url (based on the flickr gallery pagination script) which seems to reload the page without firing the scripts.js file.

Comment: I have put up a sample here which works fine on desktop but only seems to fail on mobile devices (using JQM)... http://www.new.mugsu.org.au/services/pooh_corner/

You will see at the bottom of the page that there is a flickr gallery and slightly above that is the tabs I am referring to. The tabs work on initial load of the page on a mobile device but then click on one of the pagination buttons in the flickr gallery, you will see that it seems to reload the page without firing the scripts.js file.

Again, thank you to anyone that takes the time to have a look over this for me.